# Nodejs wait for query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, promise

I'm using Nodejs with MongoDB(mongoose along with express).

Since I don't trust the user data, I need to verify it from the database.

input data:

```
{
 "id": "someid",
 "nottrusteddata": [ {"id": "1"}, {"id" :"2"}]
}
```

In my function, I'm verifying the data:

```
router.post("/validate", (req, res,next) =>{
  let validated_data = validate_data(req); 
  console.log(JSON.stringify(validated_data));
  const mydata = new Mydata({
     id: req.body.id,
     lst : validated_data   
  });
  console.log("mydata: " + JSON.stringify(mydata));
  /* Some Usefull stuff is here */
  res.status(200).json();
}

function validate_data(req){
 let validated_data = []
 for(let i = 0; i < req.body.nottrusteddata.length; i++)
 {
   Databaseobject.findOne({'id': req.body.nottrusteddata[i].id})
   .exec()
   .then(dbobject =>{
     if(dbobject) // not undefined, it exists in the database
     {
       // Some logic with the object returned from the database
       let tmp_object = {};
       tmpobject.id = dbobject.id;
       // Append it to the list, so that the upper function can use it
       validated_data.push(tmp_object);
     }
   })
 }
 return validated_data;
}
```

The desired output should contain the correct information coming from the database, however, due to the async nature of the nodejs, `validated_data` returns null.

I have also tried using `Promise`. I couldn't succeed it.

```
const validate_data = function(req){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

     let validated_data = []
     for(let i = 0; i < req.body.nottrusteddata.length; i++)
     {
       Databaseobject.findOne({'id': req.body.nottrusteddata[i].id})
       .exec()
       .then(dbobject =>{
         if(dbobject) // not undefined, it exists in the database
         {
           let tmp_object = {};
           tmpobject.id = dbobject.id;
           validated_data.push(tmp_object);
         }
       })
     }
     resolve(validated_data);
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I wait for the database query to finish, then execute the main part? If there is only one validation, I could've used `.then()`. However, the list might have contained many elements and I need to wait for all of them to be verified.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Databaseobject.findOne()` calls are asynchronous so your promise will resolve before any of them complete.

You can make use of `Promise.all` to wait until all of your promises resolve.

Hopefully, this will work for you:

```
router.post("/validate", (req, res) => {

  validate_data(req.body.nottrusteddata)
    .then(validated_data => {
      const mydata = new Mydata({
        id: req.body.id,
        lst: validated_data   
      })

      // Some useful stuff is here

      res.status(200).json()
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // Handle error
    })

}

function validate_data(nottrusteddata) {

  // Create array of pending promises
  const promises = nottrusteddata
    .map(item => {
      return Databaseobject
        .findOne({ 'id': item.id })
        .exec()
    })

  // Wait for all promises to resolve
  return Promise.all(promises)
    .then(docs => {
      return docs
        .filter(dbobject => dbobject) // Filter out undefined
        .map(dbobject => {
          return { id: dbobject.id }
        })
    })

}
```

If you want, you could also use **async-await** here:

```
router.post("/validate", async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const validated_data = await validate_data(req.body.nottrusteddata)

    const mydata = new Mydata({
      id: req.body.id,
      lst: validated_data   
    })

    // Some useful stuff is here

    res.status(200).json()
  }

  catch(err) {
    // Handle error
  }

})
```

Comment: I couldn't do async-wait. It just does not wait. However, I have waited all promises to be finished. The async function would be better because I have complex data and each part of the data needs to be checked from different database collections. Right now, I'm doing this, which is fine but it can be improved:
`check1().then(firstinfo =>{
 check2().then(secondinfo =>{...})})`

Or, I need to find a way to wait for multiple database checks rather than executing `exec.then` clauses

Comment: If the db calls don’t need to sequential then you could use `Promise.all()` again to run them all at once.